# Fan speed control on Gigabyte z170mx gaming v5 rev 1.0

Tags: motherboard, fan

#### Troubleshooting Help:

**What is your parts list?**

- Corsair Vengeance LPX (2x, 8GB, DDR4-3000, DIMM 288)
- MSI GTX 970 Gaming 4G (4GB, Midrange)
- WD Blue (500GB, 2.5", Notebook)
- Corsair H55 (5.20cm)
- Gigabyte GA-Z170MX-Gaming 5 (LGA 1151, Intel Z170, mATX)
- Corsair CS750M (750W)
- Intel Core i7 6700K BOX (LGA 1151, 4GHz, Unlocked)
- Samsung 850 Pro (256GB, 2.5")

**Describe your problem. List any error messages and symptoms. Be descriptive.**

My Problem concerns my fan speed of the hybrid pump on the motherboard: The fan has a 3 header pin, plugged into a 4 header on the motherboard. While I do know that I can't directly regulate.

**List anything you've done in attempt to diagnose or fix the problem.**

- tried to regulate in the BIOS
- google answers told me to install the Gigabyte App centre and then through the centre System Information Viewer and EasyTune.
- another way was to use speedfan software, but it doesn't even detect my fan...

So the final problem is the EasyTune engine keeps crashing or not even starting.

**Post relevant photos of build/parts here.**

-

**Provide any additional details you wish below.**

I only want to control my fan, currently it runs at full speed... which is too loud for my me and my birds lol
Any directions or hints would be much appreciated,
thanks in advance

Comment: So what exactly is your question.  You can’t control a 3-pin fan plugged into a 4-pin fan header.  Get yourself a fan controller.

Comment: another way was to use speedfan software, but it doesn't even detect my fan...

Comment: Speedfan only works if the controller is designed in such a way it can control fans with only 3 wires, your header requires 4 hence the reason it’s not being detected

Comment: I see, I thought I knew what it was about but I didn't... one last question, and please do it as answer so I can accept is as correct, would this be a fan controller i could achieve this with? https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/phobya-4pin-pwm-auf-4x-4pin-splitter-external-4x-fan-controllers-6042198?tagIds=76-526

Comment: Whichever one you want.  Hardware recommendations are out of scope.  I also don’t ever visit a Chinese based domain for security reasons

Comment: Oh ok, thanks a lot anyway, just wanted to make sure it is capable of what I need because it's in category of speed fan but is itself a splitter... :) btw top level domain .ch is "confederatio helvetica" latin term for Switzerland. CN is china :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three-pin fans use voltage control to manage the speed. Your motherboard manual ([page 14](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-z170mx-gaming5_e.pdf#page=14)) shows the SYS_FAN1/2/3 use VCC, but the cpu fan does not. In addition, page 15 shows a CPU_OPT fan header which also supports VCC.

The next step is to ensure the fan plug wires are arranged to match the motherboard CPU_OPT pinouts.

Comment: thanks for your answer, well I was sadly aware (after i bought the H55) that I couldn't control it with voltage control. So my only bet is to get SpeedFan (fan controller) to work but it doesn't even detect any... could I just plugin the fan header at a free system header?

Comment: the CPU_OPT header is for water cooler fans that require VCC (yours) according to the manual. "YES" you can use that header. The fan wires may be coded. Try and find a pin-out diagram and then look at the manual pin-out diagram to ensure the wires are connected to the correct pins

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure the fan speed control is enabled in the BIOS? Looking at the manual for your motherboard it seems you need to enable Fan Speed Control before adjusting further settings.

Also try setting the fan speed as low as possible in the BIOS to make sure it's causing a change, I've had it happen a few times I was adjusting the fan speed on the wrong port.

As one last note make sure to disable the fan speed control on whichever fan port you plugged the pump into for the H55, so it always runs at full speed. The pumps are designed to run at max all the time and varying them can cause damage.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just tested it once again to control it by setting it as low as possible, it didn't change the RPM at all or noise. well I was sadly aware (after i bought the H55) that I couldn't control it with voltage control. So my only bet is to get SpeedFan (fan controller) to work but it doesn't even detect any... could I just plugin the fan header at a free system header?

Comment: Speedfan isn’t a controller per day, when I say fan controller l, I mean hardware

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it looks like the recommendations for a hardware fan speed controller are spot on. Some motherboards can change voltage for a 3-pin fan but it looks like yours can't.

Make sure what you buy is called a "Fan speed controller" not "fan hub" or "fan splitter". Look for some sort of hardware control to manage the attached fans, like a switch or dial.